# How do I set up a PHP cron job on a webhost?

Tags: php, json, cron

I've been working on a PHP script that takes out a lot of data from a third party dynamic JSON file and writes the compressed data into a new JSON file. I know nothing about servers and webhosting, and up until today nothing about PHP. This is the PHP script:

```
<?php 
// Retrieve data
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, "http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/challenge/region?locale=en_GB");
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$leaderboardsData = curl_exec($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);
$json_a = json_decode($leaderboardsData, true);

// Two categories that will be used in writing to a new JSON file
$topItems = array();
$subItems = array();

// Filter data and store the relevant information in the two categories
foreach($json_a[challenge] as $challenge)
{
    $dungeon = $challenge[map][name];
    echo $dungeon.' ';
    foreach($challenge[groups] as $group)
    {
        $ranking = $group[ranking];
        $time_passed = time() - strtotime($group[date]);
        $hours_passed = floor($time_passed / 3600);
        $minutes_passed = floor($time_passed / 60);
        $members = '';
        foreach($group[members] as $member)
        {
            $memberName = $member[character][name];
            $memberGuild = $member[character][guild];
            $memberRealm = $member[character][realm];
            $member = $memberName.' <'.$memberGuild.'>, '.$memberRealm;
            $members .= $member;
        }
        $timer = $group[time][minutes].':'.$group[time][seconds].'.'.$group[time][milliseconds];
        if($hours_passed > 0)
        {
            $item = '#'.$ranking.' '.$dungeon.': '.$timer.' ('.$hours_passed.' hours ago)';
        }
        else
        {
            $item = '#'.$ranking.' '.$dungeon.': '.$timer.' ('.$minutes_passed.' minutes ago)';
        }
        if($minutes_passed > 0 and $hours_passed < 72)
        {
            array_push($topItems, $item);
            array_push($subItems, $members);
        }
    }
}

echo count($subItems);

// Write to file
$json_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($topItems); $i++)
{
    $json_item = json_encode(array(
        "topItem" => $topItems[$i],
        "subItem" => $subItems[$i]));
    array_push($json_array, $json_item);
}
$result = json_encode($json_array);
file_put_contents('./challenge.json', $result);
```

?>

I read something about cron jobs being a tool for scheduled tasks on servers. I would like to run the above script every few minutes to keep the data in the file it writes to fresh. How should I go about this? I am very worried that I end up paying for webhosting and not being able to make proper use of it.

Can anyone recommend me a good hosting service for this sort of thing and explain to me how I set up a cron job there?

EDIT: I managed to get my script working on a free shared host, but since I'm trying to retrieve data from Blizzard Entertainment, my IP is obviously blacklisted, so I receive only empty data. Would my problem be solved if I got VPS with cron job support? The server would have to be able to deal with a few dozens of people requesting a .JSON file about 5MB in size multiple times a day through my associated Android app. What sort of budget should I be thinking? I don't want to get an overkill of utility I don't need (for example, I don't need to also host a website or other services).

Comment: You go into your administration panel (cPanel, Plesk, etc) and add the cron there. The majority of webhosting companies allows you to create cronjobs every few minutes. Anyway, talk to them first.

Comment: We can't recommend hosts here, no - it's too subjective and depends on a wide set of variables (where you are, what you are doing, your price expectations, uptime requirements...). Are you looking for shared or VPS hosting? Shared is the simplest and cheapest, but can sometimes limit you depending on what you are wanting to do. VPS can be very inexpensive these days, but gives you root access to a "slice" of a full server. With this option, you may have to do some minor administration yourself.